# Opening a page after login doesn't work

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Using PhantomJs & CasperJs, I would like to :

1. Get the login page of a website
2. Fill the form and send it
3. Once i'm connected, get the content of an other page.

I'm stuck at step 3.

I absolutely do not understand how to get another page after the first one.

I read the documentation, many forums, etc ...

Here's my code :
(I did replace login/password and links).

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"]
});

casper.start("https://my_website/login");

casper.waitForSelector('#username', function() {

    this.fill('form#fm1', {
        'username':    "...",
        'password':    '...'
    }, true);

});

casper.then(function() {
    //this.echo('Title : ' + this.getTitle());
    //this.echo('Title : ' + this.page.content);

    // if the page contains the word "Connected", 
    // the connexion is successful
    if (this.page.content.indexOf("Connected") > -1) {
        console.log("Connected");
    }

});

casper.thenOpen('https://my_website.com/myplanning.jsp', function(response) {
    // HERE'S THE PROBLEM !!!!!!!!
    console.log(this.getPageContent());
});

casper.waitForSelector('#inner0', function() {
    // HERE'S AN OTHER PROBLEM !!!!!!!!
    console.log('Great !');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit(); 
});
```

How can I get the content of "https://my_website.com/myplanning.jsp"?

Comment: Your script looks fine. You didn't say what the problem is. If it even does, in what way does the page content look different from the expected page content. What exactly is the *other problem*? Do you mean that `Great !` doesn't appear in the terminal?

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you were right. My script was right ! After a lot of researches i had to pass as argument `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` ... Thanks ;) !